# Does AWS Batch spot fleet use a service-linked role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-batch

I'm using terraform to make an AWS Batch compute environment ([registry link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/batch_compute_environment#spot_iam_fleet_role)) and the resource wants me to specify a `spot_iam_fleet_role` role. When I read the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/spot_fleet_IAM_role.html) it seems like there are multiple spot roles I need to hand in and two are service linked?? I'm very confused.

**What role is supposed to be in `spot_iam_fleet_role` and why?**

Comment: Are you using EC2 or Fargate type?

Comment: EC2 Spot instances